# Merge a UIImageView with a UIView that contains different subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, merge, uiimage

I have a `UIImage` (called image) that i want to merge with another `UIView` (called overlayView), that contains different subviews eg. `UILabels`, `UIImageViews` and so on, to make a new `UIImage` (called mergedImage). Here's my code until now:

```
-(UIImage *) mergeViewWithImage: (UIImage *) image{
    //The mergedImage need to be the same size as the image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

    //I'm doing this to get the layer, when i renderInContext, other ways?
    UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    //This is working, the view gets its new frame, but the subviews won't scale up
    [overlayView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];


    [temp.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    [overlayView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //Need to set the frame to the initial one
    [overlayView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];

    return mergedImage;
}
```

[This screenshot is what I really want it to look like](http://oi44.tinypic.com/67jp85.jpg)

what you see is a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` (320*320), in the square, and I have a `UIView`, called overlayView (320*320), on top. When i press the "Take"-button, I do certain scaling, cropping and so on with the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`, then i run the `mergeViewWithImage`-method. At this point the image is 968*968, but the overlayView is still 320*320 (has a blue boarder, just to know where it is). When I `setFrame:` to the `overlayView`, the the subviews, eg. the example-image of Luca Toni in the left lower corner doesn't scale, as you see in this screenshot

[This is what i get](http://oi39.tinypic.com/2m2xs8l.jpg)

So you see, the background image (a white wall) stays the same, and the overlayView did resize, but the image of Luca Toni is much smaller, it wont scale... Please, help.

I've tried a lot of things, like setting this:

```
//imageOne is the picture with Luca Toni...
[[overlayView imageOne] setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

The overlayView is made in the Interface Builder as a .xib, which is a `UIView` with a `UIImageVIew` (imageOne), and has its own `UIVIew` custom class (nothing here yet, only the reference to imageOne (Luca Toni)). The overlayView is initiated in the `MainViewController`, like this:

```
[self overlayView:[[OverlayView alloc] init]];

overlayView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

and added to the main view like this:

```
[[self view] addSubview:overlayView];
```

Comment: Okey, I solved this myself. The whole problem was that the Use Autolayout in the File inspector (Interface Builder) was checked, that again prevented me from using Autosizing under Size inspector.